# system round robin using jquery bracket stage group

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need your help to show me any guide or tutorial for generationg round robin tournement exactly like world cup I need to have 8 groupe and system first win VS second win from other groupes also any way to save all this in my database please guide me realy appreciate any help from your side

I have only bracket template :

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>      
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bracket/0.11.1/jquery.bracket.min.js" integrity="sha512-BgJKmxJA3rvUEa00GOdL9BJm5+lu6V7Gx2K0qWDitRi0trcA+kS/VYJuzlqlwGJ0eUeIopW4T9faczsg8hzE/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bracket/0.11.1/jquery.bracket.min.css" integrity="sha512-8QbEO8yS//4kwUDxGu/AS49R2nVILw83kYCtgxBYk+Uw0B9S4R0RgSwvhGLwMaZuYzhhR5ZHR9dA2cDgphRTgg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        var leftBracket = {
            teams: [
                ["Kansas", "Austin Peay"],
                ["Colorado", "Connecticut"],
                ["Maryland", "South Dakota State"],
                ["California", "Hawaii"],
                ["Arizona", "Wichita State"],
                ["Miami (FL)", "Buffalo"],
                ["Iowa", "Temple"],
                ["Villanova", "UNC Asheville"],
                ["Oregon", "Holy Cross"],
                ["Saint Joseph's", "Cincinnati"],
                ["Baylor", "Yale"],
                ["Duke", "UNC Wilmington"],
                ["Texas", "Northern Iowa"],
                ["Texas A&M", "Green Bay"],
                ["Oregon State", "VCU"],
                ["Oklahoma", "Cal State Bakersfield"]
            ],
            results: [
                [
                    [[105, 79],[67, 74],[79, 74],[66, 77],[55, 65],[79, 72],[72, 70],[86, 56],[91, 52], [78, 76], [75, 79], [93, 85], [72, 75], [92, 65], [67, 75], [82, 68]],
                    [[73, 61],[73, 60],[57, 65],[68, 87],[69, 64],[64, 71],[88, 92],[81, 85]],
                    [[79, 63],[69, 92],[82, 68],[63, 77]],
                    [[59, 64],[68, 80]],
                    [[1,2]]
                ]
            ]
        };



        $(function() {
            $('div#leftBracket').bracket({
                init: leftBracket,
                skipConsolationRound: true,
            });

    
        })          
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="leftBracket" >   </div>
 
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you review the documentation: http://www.aropupu.fi/bracket/ It seems to cover everything you discussed. Is there something specifically now working in your code?

Comment: I read it but its not clear can help on this or show me a full example